# windows - how to link against API sets (*ms-win*) instead kernel32.dll, ntdll.dll etc.?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-studio-2015, linker

How do I specify explicitly to *MSVC* compiler / linker to link against [API sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/apiindex/windows-apisets) (**ms-win** pattern matcing dlls) instead *kernel32.dll*, *ntdll.dll* etc.?

For example, I've created a simple dll, which just calls a few basic WinAPIs. When examining it's IAT (via [CFF Explorer](https://ntcore.com/?page_id=388), python [pefile](https://github.com/erocarrera/pefile) library etc.) there's only *kernel32.dll*.
What I'd like to happen, is to see **ms-win** dlls instead.

Comment: Just use those libraries in the linker settings?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't as the API sets (besides the umbrella libs `OneCore[xxx].lib`) are just a set of DLLs and an API set map (the internal system memory used for the actual redirection to implementation DLLs); there are no static libs (`.lib`) file for those. You must always refer to the `Requirement` ([example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindowexa#requirements)) part of an API documentation to know which library is actually providing the API.

Comment: Why would you event want to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

API sets are used internally, meaning even the 'legacy' system DLLs on Windows 7, 8 or 10 use them. Hence there's no reason you need to use them directly.

That said, there are a number of 'umbrella' libraries you can use instead of linking against classic `KERNEL32.DLL`, etc.:

- onecore.lib
- onecoreuap.lib
- onecore_apiset.lib

Keep in mind that these are intended to match the same Windows build as the Windows 10 SDK they ship in (i.e. they are forward compatible, not backward). There are `*_downlevel.lib` versions as well which support older builds of Windows. These are all mostly intended for consumption by driver developers per [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows-hardware/drivers/develop/building-for-onecore)

UWP apps use their own umbrella library `WindowsApps.lib` / `WindowsApps_downlevel.lib`.

See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/apiindex/windows-umbrella-libraries) for more on **umbrella libraries**.

> Note that you should not link with more than one umbrella library, and you shouldn't mix kernel32.lib with umbrella libraries in the same link. This is actually a bit challenging to do with MSBuild default rules for scenarios other than `WindowsApps.lib`. There's an improvement coming in VS 2022 17.2 that addresses this. See [this VS feedback issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/microsoftcppcorewinprops-does-not-properly-support/1646747).

> Also due to a quirk of the Microsoft Visual C/C++ Runtime, if you are linking with `onecore_apiset.lib`, you should use `/IGNOREDEFAULTLIB:onecore.lib /IGNOREDEFAULTLIB:kernel32.lib` as well. It's also a good idea to use `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS,10.0` or `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE,10.0`. See [this VS feedback issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Visual-C-Runtime-forces-the-use-of-one/1644699).